# Convert compression algorithm to decompression

Tags: python, algorithm, binary, compression

sorry for the simple question, but it's blowing by brain, since I'm not good at data structure.

First, I have an initial binary file with compressed raw data. My colleague helped me out to turn the bytes into an array of decimals in Python (the code is given below and works just fine, showing the result as a chart in pyplot).

Now, I want to do the reverse operation, e.g. turn an array of decimal numbers into a binary file, but I'm totally stuck. Thank you very much in advance!

```
data_out = []

# decode 1st point
data_out.append(int.from_bytes(data_in[0:4], byteorder='big', signed=True))

i = 4
while i < len(data_in):
    # get next byte
    curr = int.from_bytes(data_in[i:i+1], byteorder='big', signed=False)
    if curr < 255:
        res = curr - 127
        data_out.append(res + data_out[-1])
        i = i + 1
    else:
        res = int.from_bytes(data_in[i+1:i+5], byteorder='little', signed=True)
        data_out.append(res)
        i = i + 5

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data_out)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Sequentially convert your data back to bytes. What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: Are you dead sure it's `curr < 255` and not `curr <= 255`/`curr < 256`?

Comment: @greybeard The `< 255` is checking for a 255 in the stream, which signals a subsequent four-byte integer. If the byte is < 255, then it is a one-byte signed integer in the range -127 to 127. So it is correct as written.

Answer (score 0):

The original stream of bytes was encoded as one or four-byte integers. The first value is sent as a four-byte integer. After the first value, you have either one byte in the range 0..254, which represents a difference of -127 to 127, or you have 255 followed by four-byte signed little-endian integer, which is the next value (not a difference). The idea is that if the integers are changing slowly from one to the next, this will compress the sequence by up to a factor of four by sending small differences as one byte instead of four. Though if you have too many differences that don't fit in a byte, this could expand the data by 25%, since non-difference values take five bytes instead of four.

To encode such a stream, you start by encoding the first value directly as four bytes, little endian. For each subsequent value, you subtract the previous value from this one. If the result is in the range -127 to 127, then add 127 and send that byte. Otherwise send a 255 byte, followed by the value (not the difference) as a four-byte signed little-endian integer.

As pointed out by @greybeard, there is an error in your colleague's code (assuming it was copied here correctly), in that `res` is not initialized. The first point decoding needs to be:

```
# decode 1st point
res = int.from_bytes(data_in[0:4], byteorder='big', signed=True)
data_out.append(res)
```

Comment: Mark, thank you very much for your help! I did copy the code wrong, since it was my first post here. But your explanation is really great, everything is clear for me now.